# Bootstrap Carousel (Cannot read property 'length' of undefined) error

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I have recently installed Laravel 5.4 version with its Auth module, and I am using bootstrap [Carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel), everything looks good, but when a user changes the slide, it gives the following error on the console and Carousel become stuck.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at n.slide (app.js:6)
at n.next (app.js:6)
at i (app.js:19)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved, once I added the latest version of [Jquery](http://jquery.com/) library.